# Is there and alternative to LIKE statement in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, contains, sql-like

**I have a scenario** where I need to perform following operation:

```
SELECT *
FROM
[dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE
[Url] LIKE '%<some url>%';
```

I have to use two % (wildcard characters) at the beginning and the end of Url (`'%<some url>%'`) as user should be able to search the complete url even if he types partial text. For example, if url is http://www.google.co.in and user types "goo", then the url must appear in search results. `LIKE` operator is causing performance issues. **I need an alternative** so that I can get rid of this statement and wildcards. In other words, **I don't want to use LIKE statement in this scenario**. I tried using T-SQL `CONTAINS` but it is not solving my problem. Is there any other alternative available than can perform pattern matching and provide me results quickly?

Comment: In what way is it causing performance issues?

Comment: I have simplified the question. Please do not delete the post.

Comment: @DavidG The query is running too slow

Comment: Are you sure it is the LIKE that is slowing it down?

Comment: Good indexing is what you need. Different operators will not help you if you don't have a proper index on that column.

Comment: @sharpcloud - An index won't really help that much as it has a leading wildcard it will still need to scan it. The best an index can do is reduce the width of the data being scanned.

Comment: There is no replacement other than like for you. you can try out creating indexes and checking the performance as explained here http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jnelson/archive/2007/11/16/108354.aspx

Comment: A full text index may help.

Comment: @MartinSmith not knowing the size of the table in question, it could still be an improvement for him. Correctly defined indexes should probably be smaller than the full table, so scanning the entire index should be faster than scanning the entire table. Apart from indexing, there are no real options.

Comment: A full index will not help either because URLs generally are seen there as one word. Full text is for "real text". A URL is one word for it - back to the same problem.

Comment: Are you only looking for base URLS like www.stackoverflow.com or are you looking for sub pages like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506879/is-there-and-alternative-to-like-statement-in-t-sql ?

Comment: @TomTom According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms142571.aspx#like) it does improve performance.

Comment: Switching to a *begins with* is how this is often done and matches your example, its also optimisable.

Comment: @AlexK. How does *begins with* help finding `www.google.com` when searching for `goog`?

Comment: It does not. Some people love to ignore as much of the question as does not fit them.

Comment: there is an alternative to LIKE called PATINDEX. However this will not help you with your current problem.

Comment: @DavidG Contains is FullText

Answer (score 9):

Starting a like with a % is going to cause a scan.  No getting around it.  It has to evaluate every value.

If you index the column it should be an index (rather than table) scan.

You don't have an alternative that will not cause a scan.
Charindex and patindex are alternatives but will still scan and not fix the performance issue.

Could you break the components out into a separate table?
www
google
co
in

And then search on like 'goo%'?
That would use an index as it does not start with %.

Better yet you could search on 'google' and get an index seek.

And you would want to have the string unique in that table with a separate join on Int PK so it does not return multiple www for instance.

Suspect FullText Contains was not faster because FullText kept the URL as one word.

Comment: How does this answer the question "Is there any alternative to LIKE statement in T-SQL?"

Comment: @MartinSmith But there is not alternative that will correct the performance issue.

Comment: So if that's your answer put it in the answer. At the moment this in no way answers the OP's original question which was asking for an alternative to LIKE not an explanation of LIKE.

Comment: @Blam no, with an index the leading % will cause an **index** scan, which is still faster than a table scan. The actual result will obviously depend on his exact situation.

Comment: Not really. OR: Only if most of the data is stale and otherwise not used. Otherwise we are down to RAM Speeds and keeping the table AND the index in memory, compared to only the table.

Comment: @Blam splitting the url field into a separate table with components could certainly improve speed, however it adds a load of complexity if the system should support editing the urls. +1 from me.

Comment: @TomTom too many if's/uncertainties in your comment to really deny my point to be honest :) Also, hardware is dirt cheap nowadays.

Comment: @sharpcloud Man, I live in a land where hardware still costs money. Try putting a 3tb ram server into a rack please. And yes, that is the size of active data I am working with daily.

Comment: The idea is good. As it is usually the domain users type in, why not have a separate (even redundant) column for it and limit searches to "domain begins with"? "goo%" will find "http://google.com" as much as "www.google.com". "oogl%" will not find anything, but it's not likely to be used when looking for Google anyway. As the expression doesn't start with '%', an index search may be used (especially as there is still only one column to check, so no ORs). +1 from me.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner But if you make it unique (for speed) then www, com, ... are only done once.  Then use a many to many table to link it.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I misread. Still, I think that most people would look for the domain, so a column for that would suffice plus an index on it to look it up. Even if a user typed "www.goo" I would look for `WHERE domain like "goo%" AND url like "%WWW.goo%". However, this takes some thinking when it comes to looking for "all.toys" - "all" is a subdomain or part of; but is "toys" the domain or only a subdomain, too? ...

Comment: ... So, you are right, a lookup table to find "toys" for both "all.toys.com" and "all.toys.gifts.com" would make this task simple and fast.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [FULLTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms142571.aspx) index.

First create your catalog:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;
```

Now assuming your table is called `MyTable`, the column is `TextColumn` and it has a unique index on it called `UX_MyTable_TextColumn`:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[MyTable](TextColumn) 
    KEY INDEX UX_MyTable_TextColumn
```

Now you can search the table using CONTAINS:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS(TextColumn, 'searchterm')
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it doesn't work. Searching for "goo" will not yield "`http://www.google.com`". Searching for "google" does, and as long as what you're searching for is word-like, this can help.

Comment: How about searching for `*goo*`?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Neither does "goo*". I should immediately confess that I've never used full-text indexes, precisely because, once I read up on them, I figured they couldn't do what I want.

Comment: Aha, success. If I use `CONTAINS(TextColumn, '"goo*"')` it returns a hit -- mind the double quotes. But don't get too enthusiastic -- `CONTAINS(TextColumn, '"*oogle*"')` still yields nothing. I'd say the full-text index option needs a lot of careful testing.

Comment: FTS contains can only use trailing wildcards. If it doesn't start with `goo`, then it'll never be returned. There doesn't seem to be a way around this, other than sticking with `LIKE '%goo%'`

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there's no alternative to `like` or `contains` (full text search feature) which would give better performance.
What you can do is try to improve performance by optimising your query.
To do that, you need to know a bit about your users & how they'll use your system.
I suspect most people will enter a URL from the start of the address (i.e. without protocol), so you could do something like this:

```
declare @searchTerm nvarchar(128) = 'goo'
set @searchTerm = coalesce(replace(@searchTerm ,'''',''''''),'')
select @searchTerm

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE [Url] LIKE 'http://' + @searchTerm + '%'
or [Url] LIKE 'https://' + @searchTerm + '%'
or [Url] LIKE 'http://www.' + @searchTerm + '%'
or [Url] LIKE 'https://www.' + @searchTerm + '%'
or [Url] LIKE '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
option (fast 1); --get back the first result asap;
```

That then gives you some optimisation; i.e. if the url's http://www.google.com the index on the url column can be used since http://www.goo is at the start of the string.
The `option (fast 1)` piece on the end's to ensure this benefit is seen; since the last `URL like %searchTerm%` can't make use of indexes, we'd rather return responses as soon as we can rather than wait for that slow part to complete.
Have a think of other common usage patterns and ways around those.

Comment: That would be relevant if it would work - sadly I think the optimizer will just make a table scan BECAUSE IT HAS TO ANYWAY - instead of using multiple search paths and then the tempdb to get rid of doubles. Requires a test though, but I think it is a totally non working trick here. What would work is removing the protocol (into a separate field) for example...

Comment: @TomTom agreed that removing the protocol would be better - maybe having a second search column which strips the protocol and converts from nvarchar to varchar; using this second column only for searching.  Better yet would be Blam's solution above; i.e. parse the URL and search on its component parts.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your query cannot be further optimized, and there is no way of getting around the `LIKE` to do your searching. The only thing you can do to improve performance is reduce the `SELECT` to return only the columns you need if you don't need all of them, and create an index on `URL` with those columns included. The `LIKE` will not be able to use the index for seeking, but the reduced data size for scanning can help. If you have a SQL Server edition that supports compression, that will help as well.

For instance, if you really need only column A, write

```
SELECT A FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE [Url] LIKE '%<some url>%';
```

And create the index as

```
CREATE INDEX IX_MyTable_URL 
ON MyTable([Url]) 
INCLUDE (A) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);
```

If A is already included in your primary key, the INCLUDE is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a very simple one and I see no reason for it to be slow. The dbms wil read record for record and compare strings. Usually it can even do this in parallel threads.

What do you think can be the reason for your statement being so slow? Are there billions of records in your table? Do your records contain so much data?

Your best bet is not to care about the query, but about the database and your system. Others have already suggested an index on the url column, so rather than scanning the table, the index can be scanned. Is max degree of parallelism mistakenly set? Is your table fragmented? Is your hardware appropriate? These are the things to consider here.

However: `charindex('oogl', url) > 0` does the same as `url like '%oogl%'`, but internally they work differently somehow. For some people the LIKE expression turned out faster, for others the CHARINDEX method. Maybe it depends on the query, number of processors, operating system, whatever. It may be worth a try.