# Fulltext column mysql dont find 'client' in word 'clients'

Tags: mysql, sql, fulltext-index

I have a varchar column that contains the word clients. It is fulltext with clients data. I am failing to locate the row when searching by word client. I am hoping to avoid LIKE because of number of records. Is LIKE the only way to go? I read that WITH QUERY EXPANSION might help but the shared mysql server i am using does not recognize it.

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there and alternative to LIKE statement in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506879/is-there-and-alternative-to-like-statement-in-t-sql)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038590/alternative-to-like-clause-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcard search in MySQL full-text search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679696/wildcard-search-in-mysql-full-text-search)